# MongoDB Configuration file not present on windows environment

Tags: node.js, mongodb, replicaset

I am a newbie on MongoDB. Now I need Replica set for my MongoDB. For that when I go to Tutorial there is mentioned that first, you have to make some changes to the configuration file. But unfortunately, there is no file.

After some research on MongoDB Documentation, I got some idea. the link is

> https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#configure-a-windows-service-for-mongodb-community-edition

Now I am a little bit confuse how to start three instances for the replica set.

```
 I also read that under C:/data/ I have to create a folder for replicas like rs1, rs2, and rs3.
```

> Initially I am able to start my mongoDB services With the Code i.e net
>   start Mongodb

and for creating the members on replica First I type the command i.e

> mongo --port 27017

after that I will create the members for Replica set i.e

```
config =  {_id: "test", members: [
    {_id: 0, host: "127.0.0.1:27017"},
    {_id: 1, host: "127.0.0.1:27018"},
    {_id: 2, host: "127.0.0.1:27019"}
]}
```

after Entering this When I type the command on my cmd i.e

```
rs.initiate(config)
it gives me the error i.e 
{
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "This node was not started with the replSet option",
        "code" : 76,
        "codeName" : "NoReplicationEnabled"
}
```

I don't know now what I can Do. i am sharing my Configuration file content
 i.e

```
# mongod.conf

systemLog:
    destination: file
    path: c:\data\log\mongod.log

storage:
    dbPath: c:\data\db
```

Shall any more thing I have to add to this file.
Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Hi Abhay; it looks (from your other question this morning) that you've found the solution yourself. In that case, the appropriate thing to do here is to [add an answer to your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), and [accept it](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) to take your question off the unanswered list.